# Python - Create new list from a list by applying filter

Tags: python, list

I have a list below:

```
list = [NEW - FROM VOLUNTARY SECTOR,NEW - FROM PUBLIC SECTOR,
LEAVER - RESIGNED,LEAVER - RETIRED,NEW - FROM PRIVATE SECTOR,
SECONDEE PRIVATE SECTOR,SECONDEE VOLUNTARY SECTOR]
```

Is there a way to create a new list from above list which has all values except values starting with word 'NEW'. So my example output would look like:

```
sublist = [LEAVER - RESIGNED,LEAVER - RETIRED,
SECONDEE PRIVATE SECTOR,SECONDEE VOLUNTARY SECTOR]
```

I feel I should be able to loop over the list using

```
for x in list:
    if list(x)!="NEW*":
        sublist.append(x)
```

But can't get this to work

Comment: try `if not x.startswith('NEW')`

Comment: Your `list` is not valid Python and should be renamed so it doesn't shadow a built-in.

Comment: If you need to find more complex patterns, use regex for each item in the list. An alternative easy solution would be to use string splicing. Eg- `if x[:3].upper() == "NEW": do something`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
x = ['NEW - FROM VOLUNTARY SECTOR','NEW - FROM PUBLIC SECTOR','LEAVER - RESIGNED','LEAVER - RETIRED','NEW - FROM PRIVATE SECTOR','SECONDEE PRIVATE SECTOR','SECONDEE VOLUNTARY SECTOR']

y = [i for i in x if not i.startswith("NEW")]

print(y)
```

Output:

```
['LEAVER - RESIGNED', 'LEAVER - RETIRED', 'SECONDEE PRIVATE SECTOR', 'SECONDEE VOLUNTARY SECTOR']
```